# Centering rotated labels when x-axis is at the top

Tags: r, ggplot2

A standard trick for centering rotated labels is to use `vjust`. It works as expected when the axis is at the bottom:

```
library( ggplot2 )
gg <- ggplot( mtcars, aes(hp, mpg) ) + geom_point() + theme_bw()
gg + theme( axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, vjust=0.5) )
```

The blue outline shows that the labels are properly centered relative to the axis ticks.

[image: x axis on the bottom]

However, I seem unable to achieve the same effect when the x axis is positioned at the top:

```
gg + theme( axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, vjust=0.5) ) +
  scale_x_continuous(position="top")
```

[image: x axis on the top]

Furthermore, it appears that `vjust` has no effect when the x axis is at the top. I found no visual difference when I changed `vjust` to 0 or to 1. Searching around for related posts, I found [a GitHub issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/1435) where it is suggested to use `margin()` instead of `hjust`/`vjust`. However, I was not able to get it to center my labels regardless of whether the x axis was positioned at the top or the bottom:

```
# Top and bottom margins properly increase space between labels and axis ticks / title
gg + theme( axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, margin=margin(t=10)) )   # Works
gg + theme( axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, margin=margin(b=10)) )   # Works

# Left and right margins appear to have no effect
gg + theme( axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, margin=margin(r=10)) )   # No effect
gg + theme( axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, margin=margin(l=10)) )   # No effect
```

Is there a trick for getting labels centered when the x-axis is at the top? I suppose I can always go digging through the hierarchy of grobs, but I was hoping there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: This is definitely a bug.  Helpful note: set `debug=TRUE` for the `element_text(...)` command.  It will draw a faint yellow box around the text element and then add yellow points where the text elements are anchored.  When angle=0, set `vjust=` and `hjust=` to different values and you'll see the anchor points moving around.  When you do that with the text at the top, `vjust=` no longer does anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `axis.text.x.top` instead:

```
gg + theme( axis.text.x.top =element_text(angle=90, vjust=.5)  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(position="top")
```

[image]

Strange since the rotate still works. I'd like to see the package clarify this, but you can still get the behavior you're after